# problem with quartz configuration: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

i'm new with quartz and i have some problem when configuration. So i have to go around the internet to find my problem but i cant do it somehow

im using sql server and jdbcstore

here is my quartz properties

```java
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.makeSchedulerThreadDaemon = true
org.quartz.scheduler.misfirePolicy =  doNothing
# 
##============================================================================
## Configure ThreadPool
##============================================================================
# 
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.makeThreadsDaemons = true
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 3
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 3

# 
##============================================================================
## Configure JobStore
##============================================================================
# 
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX 
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered true
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = ODM
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 25000
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000
## 
## 
###============================================================================
### Configure Datasources  
###============================================================================
## 
org.quartz.dataSource.ODM.driver = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
org.quartz.dataSource.ODM.URL = jdbc:sqlserver://cloudprc391.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=Quartz;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
org.quartz.dataSource.ODM.user = cloudprc391
org.quartz.dataSource.ODM.password = Q!234567
org.quartz.dataSource.ODM.maxConnections = 5
org.quartz.dataSource.ODM.validationQuery = select 1
org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.class = org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.cleanShutdown = true
```

and here is my quartconfig class

```java
package com.odmworker;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.quartz.*;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.*;

/**
 *
 * @author ADMIN
 */
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude= {QuartzAutoConfiguration.class})
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.odmworker.JobTask")
public class QuartzConfig {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QuartzConfig.class);
//    @Autowired
//    List<Trigger> listOfTrigger;

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public QuartzConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext, DataSource dataSource) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringBeanJobFactory springBeanJobFactory() {
        AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return jobFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler(Trigger... triggers) {

        SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        //Properties properties = new Properties();
        schedulerFactory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
        schedulerFactory.setAutoStartup(true);
        //schedulerFactory.setQuartzProperties(properties);
        schedulerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        schedulerFactory.setJobFactory(springBeanJobFactory());
        schedulerFactory.setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        if (ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty(triggers)) {
            schedulerFactory.setTriggers(triggers);
        }
        return schedulerFactory;
    }
```

and my job class

```java
package com.odmworker.JobTask;

import com.odmworker.Service.IJobService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.quartz.DisallowConcurrentExecution;
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Slf4j
@Component
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class JobFind implements Job{
    @Autowired
    private IJobService jobService;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jec) throws JobExecutionException {
       jobService.setQueueJob();
        //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Waiting for new Job...");

    }

}
```

and finally application.properties

```java
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://cloudprc391.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=ODM;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
spring.datasource.username=cloudprc391
spring.datasource.password=Q!234567
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
server.port=8080
```

first try, my scheduler works fine within my job class and app.properties
but i cannot using DI(autowired,inject) to inject my service class in to job 
when i search around the internet to find my solution then i added 2 others config class.
but i cannot start and the output is:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'scheduler'; nested exception is org.springframework.scheduling.SchedulingException: Could not start Quartz Scheduler; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR. [See nested exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR.]]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:893) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.odmworker.WorkerApplication.main(WorkerApplication.java:23) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.scheduling.SchedulingException: Could not start Quartz Scheduler; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR. [See nested exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR.]]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.start(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:802) ~[spring-context-support-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery.
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:697) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start(QuartzScheduler.java:539) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.start(StdScheduler.java:142) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.startScheduler(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:727) ~[spring-context-support-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.start(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:799) ~[spring-context-support-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR.
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.executeSQL(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:184) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.DBSemaphore.obtainLock(DBSemaphore.java:113) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3857) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:839) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:695) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:na]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Line 1: FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:259) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1547) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:548) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:479) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7344) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2713) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:224) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:204) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:401) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.executeSQL(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:123) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:na]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

i really need some help, thank you

Comment: Could you try adding this property in the quartz.properties file org.quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL=SELECT * FROM {0}LOCKS UPDLOCK WHERE LOCK_NAME = ?.  It seems the sql server doesnot like for update for some reason.